# Cannot create simple Git alias in MinGW32 on windows 7

Tags: windows, git, alias, mingw32

I am trying to create a very simple alias. I want alias the following command:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all -- decorate
```

I find this command a very useful way to view the log file. I want to alias this line as `git l` because its the main way I wish to view the log file. This is my attempt to create the alias:

```
git config --global alias .l "git log --oneline --graph --all -- decorate"
```

This line executes without error, but then any attempt to call `git l` results in the following error message.

```
Expansion of alias 'l' failed; 'git' is not a git command
```

It was explained that working environment, windows 7, minGW32, and git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0 could have something to do with this issue, but I am not sure how to resolve this. Thank you to anyone who helps out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
git config --global alias.l "log --oneline --graph --all --decorate"
```

To call something other than a git command, you would prefix it with an exclamation point:

```
git config --global alias.foo "!foo --do-something"
```

In your case, it could've been:

```
git config --global alias.l "!git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, what I should have been typing was `git config --global alias .l "log --oneline --graph --all -- decorate"`

Comment: In my case I had to add a space before the `!` otherwise it said `Expansion of alias 'visual' failed; 'gitk' is not a git command`